# Rails routes.rb assistance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, custom-routes

thanks in advance for your help!!

I have in `routes.rb`:

```
get 'api/streets:name' => 'streets#get_by_name', as: "get_by_name"
```

I have in `streets_controller.rb`:

```
ids = params[:name]
```

I have in Javascript:

```
const params = encodeURI('name[]=1&name[]=2')
fetch(`/api/streets?${params}`)
```

When I call the api from the front end, I get the following log message:

```
Started GET "/api/streets?name%5B%5D=2&name%5B%5D=5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-09-06 17:10:59 -0700
   Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Processing by PagesController#index as */*
   Parameters: {"name"=>["2", "5"], "path"=>"api/streets"}
   Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.1ms)
   Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
```

Why is it using the PagesController and not the StreetsController?

In all other cases where I'm getting and posting and putting and deleting on the api, the router knows what controller to use.  It's just this one case when I'm using array parameters where it's routing to the wrong controller.

It's probably just something dumb I've done.

Comment: `'api/streets:name'` is a nonsense route. As already stated, remove the `:name`, it's not doing what you think it's doing. You don't need it there to use a query string in your route.

Comment: so my route should just be `get 'api/streets' => 'streets#get_by_name', as: "get_by_name"`?  And then in the controller I should just still look for the name params?  I'm going to try that.

Comment: Yep that was it.  Thanks to you @meager and @smathy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route expects a path like: `/api/streets123` - where `params[:name]` would be equal to `"123"` and no, that's not a typo.

You should just use:

```
get 'api/streets' => 'streets#get_by_name', as: "get_by_name"
```

If you need to enforce the existence of the `:name` parameter then you should use [the `:constraints` option](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @smathy!  I'm not sure I understand... if I want to pass in an array you're saying I would have to use the constraints option?

Comment: No, if you have other routes that conflict with this one, but you want this one to map to the `get_by_name` action, then you may need to use constraints to do that.  If this is the only GET for `api/streets` then you'll be fine.

Comment: I have no other routes that conflict with this one.  So then it should work, and it should route to the streets controller, right?  I must be doing something wrong somewhere.  It's reading the parameters correctly, just routing to the wrong controller.... perhaps its the question mark in the JS url

Comment: nope ... that just makes it fail to parse the array

Comment: I see what you're saying now. THANKS !! you have no idea the pressure I have atm.  :)